# Google Colab Pro+ Timeout

Tags: timeout, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab to train yolov3 on a custom data-set. I have about 200000 iterations to run to finish the training. I decided to subscribe to Colab Pro+ subscription and initially the runtime was 24 hours and now it has gone down to less than 12 hours. I am not really sure why the runtime is being interrupted/stopped.
I know that there was no error while training yolov3 with custom data-set, so the runtime is being interrupted by timeout.